# Proper way to dynamically add functions to ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, idioms

I have a simple class with a single method `exec(arg1,..,argn)` and I want to have a number of alias methods which call `exec` with predefined argument values (e.g. `exec_sync = exec.bind(this, true)`).

The following does the trick:

```js
class Executor {
  constructor() {
    this.exec_sync = this.exec.bind(this, true);
  }

  exec(sync, cmd, args/* ... */) {
    // impl
  }
}
```

**But** I don't know if this is a good idea or if this is idiomatic to ES6.

**UDATE:**

In a real-life example I have two nested loops with respectively 3 and 4 loops, which are used to dynamically add a total number of 12 alias methods to the class. It would be a cumbersome task to explicitly define the alias methods when you actually can take advantage of JS being a prototype-based programming language.

**UPDATE 2 - EXAMPLE:**

Suppose we have have a simple HTTP client with a method `request(method, body)` and we want to provide alias methods for `GET`, `PUT`, etc. It would look something like the following:

```js
class HTTP {
  constructor() {
    ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DEL'].forEach((method) => {
      this[method] = this.request.bind(this, method);
    }, this);
  }

  request(method, body) {
    // execute the HTTP request
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not create multiple functions explicitly? `exec_sync(...args) { return this.exec(true, ...args); }`

Comment: @zerkms I think that would be more clear what the class does. I was just interested about the possibility of doing something like that.

Comment: ES6 classes are just syntactic sugar. Nothing changed in terms of adding properties to an object at runtime.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your solution is fine, though it'll be better to create all those methods once on a `prototype` level:

```
['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DEL'].forEach((method) => {
  Executor.prototype[method] = function (body) {
    return this.request(method, body)
  }
})
```

`prototype` approach is slightly faster, because this code is executed only once, while constructor code is executed every time new instance is created.

Another advantage of `prototype` over `constructor` is that its compatible with classes inheritance. So, if you'll extend your class later nothing will break even if you'll redefine any of those methods.

By the way, you can use `require('http').METHODS` or [`methods` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/methods) instead of hard-coded array of HTTP verbs here.

Comment: Thanks. the http stuff should have been an example, I don't use it in my code :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89272/discussion-between-yan-foto-and-leonid-beschastny).

Answer (score 4):

I like @leonid's answer, but is there a way to allow mangling when you using dynamic computed property names.

```
['VERYBIGNAME', 'VERYBIGNAME2', 'VERYBIGNAME3'].forEach((method) => {
   Executor.prototype[method] = function (body) {
     return this.request(method, body)
   }
})
```

in your minified and mangled javascript these VERYBIGNAME strings will exist.

so if I am able to get references to these VERYBIGNAME functions can I use something like

```
const references = { VERYBIGNAME1, VERYBIGNAME2, VERYBIGNAME3 };

Object.assign(Executor.prototype, { ...references });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this being idiomatic (since it's more about design, rather than programming language itself), but I personally think creating explicit functions would be better:

```
exec_sync(...args) {
    return this.exec(true, ...args); 
}
```

Comment: In a real-life example I have 2 nested loops that respectively have 3 and 4 items  used to dynamically add a total of 12 items to the class. it would be a little cumbersome to add everything manually.

Comment: @YanFoto I would think about moving it to a separate class actually then.

Comment: Those methods actually and semantically belong to the class. If I move them to a separate class, I would still need to define them explicitly. or am I missing something here?

Comment: @YanFoto those are just helpers-wrappers. But again, it's a matter of taste or preferences in design. There is no single *objective* answer for that.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I provided an example to clarify the situation in some extent. I want to avoid the next developer considering my code as *ugly* :D

Comment: @YanFoto every code is ugly unless it's written by yourself ;-D

Comment: this is inefficient, defeats the purpose, but would work

Comment: @AlexanderMills inefficient compared to *what*?

Comment: ok it's simple, you have defined this.exec as a top level function, which means it's called every time a new object is created by the constructor, if you use the prototype function with having to define exec in the constructor, it would be better. But it appears that ES6 makes it difficult to have "dynamic" prototypes.

Comment: @AlexanderMills "you have defined this.exec as a top level function" --- I have not. It's a class method. "which means it's called every time a new object is created by the constructor" --- it won't, it's a class method, so it will be created on a prototype.